# getItem from localStorage does not shows all the data

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 input field in another component that render 4 input value typed by the user and add them to the localstorage. This creates 4 different arrays. I am trying to group this 4 arrays in one common array in this component.Tried to implement an useState but the problem is that when I console.log I always get this [Array(1)] with just the last value that the user types.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FilterMenu from "./selectButton";
import FetchRandomBet from "./fetchRandomBets";

function Betslip() {
    const data = [
        {
            value: 0,
            label: "No Filter"
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            label: "Less than two"
        },
        {
            value: 2,
            label: "More than two"
        },
    ]

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0);
    const [allStakes, setAllStakes] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = obj => {
        setSelectedValue(obj.value);
    }

    const betNow = () => {
        const stakes = localStorage.getItem("stakes");
        const jsnStake = JSON.parse(stakes) || [];
        setAllStakes([jsnStake]);
    }

    console.log(allStakes)

    return (
        <div className="betslip">
            <div className="betslip-top">
                <h1 className="text">BETSLIP</h1>
                <p className="text-two">BET WITH US!</p>
                <div>
                    <FilterMenu
                        optionsProp={data}
                        valueProp={selectedValue}
                        onChangeProp={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <FetchRandomBet
                    valueProp={selectedValue}
                />
            </div>
            <Button
                onClick={betNow}
                className="betnow"
                variant="contained"
            >
                Bet Now!
                </Button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Betslip;
```

component that sets the localStorage. It stores all the inputs in stakes as when I console log it renders all the value perfectly in order but in the component on the top when I try to access and get the item I always get just the last one.This component is conditionally rendered 4 times.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Stake() {
    const [stakes, setStakes] = useState([]);

    const addStake = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newStake = e.target.stake.value;
        setStakes([newStake]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const json = JSON.stringify(stakes);
        localStorage.setItem("stakes", json);
    });

    console.log(stakes)

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     const json = JSON.stringify(stakes);
    //     localStorage.setItem("stakes", json);
    // }, [stakes]); //get explanation of [stakes]

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={addStake}>
                <input
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: "40px",
                        width: "50px"
                    }}
                    type="text"
                    name="stake"
                    required
                />
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

Comment: Show the component which saves inputs to localStorage as well, please. You say you're expecting 4 different arrays but this component is only getting from one storage key.

Comment: I re-edited the whole question, if you need more details just ask thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` will overwrite any data on that key in storage. It will not automatically concat data structures for you, which your code seems to imply you think it will. If you have four `Stake` components, then any time one of them rerenders, it will overwrite the `stakes` key in localStorage with the local state from *that component only*.

If you need to update an array in storage, you must first extract it, then modify and replace it:

```
const addStake = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newStake = e.target.stake.value;
    const oldStakes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stakes")) || [];
    localStorage.setItem("stakes", JSON.stringify([...oldStakes, newStake]));
};
```

I've removed the call to `setStakes` and moved all the logic out of the `useEffect` since they are both unnecessary in the component you have shown, the effect especially. You can add them back in if genuinely required.

However, this whole business with pushing state into localStorage makes me a bit nervous. This is error-prone and should not be necessary for simple communication between sibling components in a React application. Have a think about whether you should really be [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Do you recommend a different approach to that?Also, how can I do for example if there is already some data betnow should not add more data?thanks

Comment: const betNow = () => {
        if (!allStakes) {
            const stakes = localStorage.getItem("stakes");
            const jsnStake = JSON.parse(stakes) || [];
            setAllStakes([jsnStake]);
            console.log(allStakes)
        } else if (allStakes) {
            console.log('already in');
        }
    }

Comment: I've tried to implement that but it always logs 'already in'. React is making me crazy..

Comment: `allStakes` starts as an empty array - empty arrays are truthy so the conditional path `!allStakes` will never run. Perhaps you want `if (allStakes.length === 0)`, or you should initialise `allStakes` as undefined or null. About localStorage - it is really for persisting things like authentication tokens, and initial app state, not for passing around bits of data while the application is running. Perhaps your `Stake` component should be sending its data to a parent component it has in common with `Betslip`, so that the latter can access it immediately. Look at the link I included.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lawrence you're great !